# Why does Google Cache show our G+ page and not the correct page?

Tags: google-search, canonical-url, google-index, google-plus, google-cache

For some reason when we try and view the cached version of our website, we see our Google plus page.

We recently removed this code : `<link rel="canonical" href="link to our g+ page">`.

We removed this and Google started seeing our homepage correctly. But we are now having the same problem for each of our internal pages and cannot seem to find this same piece of code of any of the other pages. Are we looking for the wrong thing? Or in the wrong place? We're very new to WordPress so any advice would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well from what I have read you noticed that using `"<link rel="canonical" href="link to our g+ page">` was a bad idea and have removed these entries which is a good thing. You should now do the following:

**Link Canonical**

Link Canonical is good and you should use it on every page but rather than the G Plus link with your own page so for example:

On the main page have: `"<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/">`
On deeper pages have: `"<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/page-name/">`

You should also ensure that no link canonical's to Google plus is active on any page, I'm sure you done this but double check to ensure this link is on no other pages as Google Cache will use the canonical link.

**Google Cache Time**

It's important to note that Google Cache is not real time compared to the actual search results, it can take days, weeks and even months to update the cache - this doesn't mean that your pages are not ranking. The idea of Google Cache has nothing to do with rankings but is to give Google search more features for the end users.

Google + Publisher Link

I'm sure your using something similar already but for the likes of other people with similar question you can use the Publisher link in the head of your pages like so:

```
<link href="https://plus.google.com/YourGoogleID-here" rel="publisher"/>
```